# ParseCrashReporting ,[Errno 18] Cross-device link

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Sorry for my bad english.
I had implemented the new parse feature in my IOS project,i have read the parse tutorial and these are the steps:

1 Download the latest version of the Parse CLI

```
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
```

2 Initialize a new Parse Cloud Code directory by running the following (for example, in the same directory as your Xcode project):

```
parse new
```

3 Add a new Run Script Phase to the Build Phases section of your app's target:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd /Volumes/user/Users/piero/Downloads/MyProject/parse
parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

but i have the [Errno 18] Cross-device link.

Now i have downloaded the parse sample project,and i have the same error.
Why?
Thanks

Comment: can you give the screenshot of the error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v89ji3fxjefbw2b/3.png

Answer (score 0):

At a wild guess, the folder that contains the dsym files is not on the same file system as the parse project, which is causing the error because parse tries to use hardlinks to reference files. You should configure the project to build on the same file system as your project:- under preferences -> Locations mark `DerivedData` as `Relative`.

This should only be considered a workaround, and not an actual fix to the issue - I would file a bug against parse that it doesn't work when the project does not reside on the same file system as the derived data.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put the script.
The error is still. My project has three target if it can be of help

Comment: So having changed the `DerivedData` folder in the preferences you did a clean and rebuild and the error about `Cross-device link` is still present? Can you edit the question to add the output from the error?

Comment: here's some screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yn9ix7xek4okag/1.png?dl=0       https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjepoig60bmdffo/2.png?dl=0             https://www.dropbox.com/s/v89ji3fxjefbw2b/3.png?dl=0                I think the problem is related to cocoapods.   I have tried my build location in : Unique,Custom,Shared Folder.